# What causes pre to be higher than code in reveal.js?

Tags: html, css, reveal.js, pre

I am building slides with reveal.js but for some reason `pre` blocks are taking up more height than they should. In the example screenshots, the `pre` block is taller than the `code` block by about 90 pixels.

But the CSS does not seem to indicate why. `pre` does not have a height defined and `code` does not have that amount of padding, so I don't understand why it is taking up so much space.

Why is `pre`'s height so much higher than `code`? Why does `pre` not simply wrap `code` and match its height?

```
<section>
  <h3>Property: Font-size</h3>
  <p>The font-size property speciﬁes the size of the font.</p>
  <pre>
    <code data-trim>
      p {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        font-size: 100%;
      }
    </code>
  </pre>
  <p>Pixels</p>
  <p>"em"</p>
  <p>Percentage</p>
</section>
```

`pre` block highlighted - css on left, box model on right

[image: pre block with css]
[image: pre block with box model]

`code` block highlighted - css on left, box model on right

[image: code block with css]
[image: code block with box model]

Comment: Pics are too small

Comment: Please put the code in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/1739000). This helps you and us reproduce the problem, and it may even help you understand it better.

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? I do see that on the revealjs website, it has CSS saying `.reveal pre.stretch code {  height: 100%; max-height: 100%;` and stuff.

Comment: I've added the code used to create the slide. Is there a way I can put Reveal into a stack snippet?

Comment: I've also made the images clickable so they point to the larger versions of the images

Answer (score 2):

Months have passed since you posted your question, and reveal has changed (it's not even clear what version of reveal you were using).

My `black.css` shows this CSS, which has a `max-height` setting:

```css
.reveal pre code {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 400px;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

If I modify it in the Developer Tools of Chrome, I can see the height change.

Try clicking on Computed for the CSS styles in Developer Tools to see everything. I was using Black theme with the GitHub highlight.js theme. You can drill down from there to see where the height and/or padding is coming from:

[image]